# How do I get link URLs from the Wordpress links backend into an array?

Tags: links, rss, array, feed, get-bookmarks

I'm currently running a blogroll on a site I'm working on by defining a variable with an array that has all the rss feed urls I want to pull from. Like this for example:

```
<?php // Get RSS Feed(s)
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
$rsslist = array(   'http://jordanshipman.lt11.com/rss',
            'http://feeds.feedburner.com/climbingnarc',
            'http://jonglassberg.lt11.com/rss'
                );
$rss = fetch_feed($rsslist);
if (!is_wp_error( $rss ) ) : 
$maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(25); 
$rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems); 
endif;
?>
```

What I would like to figure out is rather than entering in each feed url in the code as above I want to pull the rss links from the wordpress links backend. Using something like the wp_get_bookmarks() function. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you're looking for the [`get_bookmarks()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bookmarks) function, which returns an array of bookmark objects. You could then implement this into your code:

```
<?php // Get RSS Feed(s)
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');

$bookmarks = get_bookmarks();
$rsslist = array();

foreach ( $bookmarks as $bm ) {
    if ( $bm->link_rss )
        $rsslist[] = $bm->link_rss;
}

$rss = fetch_feed( $rsslist );

if ( ! is_wp_error( $rss ) ) {
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(25); 
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, $maxitems ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I had to change your usage/syntax a little (submitted edit) to get it to work but that's the ticket! Sub question: when I manually entered the rss urls into the code the posts in my blogroll were sorted by date. Using this mehtod, all the posts for one rss feed are displayed by date, then another, etc. They are grouped together by feed source rather than all the posts being mixed together sorted by date. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Have a look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73539/19726 - it seems that it could be one of your feeds messing things up

Comment: Thanks for the link. That post was helpful when I was getting started putting this together. I don't think it's one of the feeds as everything works fine with the same exact rss urls entered manually.

Comment: I'm sorry then, I can't think of what the problem could be - unless the arrays are structured differently. Perhaps you could post this as a new question?

Comment: No worries! You helped a lot and I appreciate it very much :) I just posted it as a new question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75535/how-to-use-get-bookmarks-fetch-feed-together-so-items-are-merged-sorted